# Unable to install Eclipse in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, java, eclipse

I am new to Ubuntu. Currently I am using Ubuntu 16.04 
I would like to install Eclipse

I have followed the steps mentioned in this document
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/01/how-to-install-the-latest-eclipse-in-ubuntu-16-04-15-10/

But at the 3rd step I get the following error

[An error has occurred please see the log file null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mezCp.png)

Upon checking for the error via the terminal I am getting the following

```
shiv@shiv-HP-Notebook:~/Softwares/Eclipse/eclipse-installer$ ./eclipse-inst 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.<init>(Storage.java:101)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.createStorage(Storage.java:88)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>    (EquinoxContainer.java:66)
at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.<init>(Equinox.java:31)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:303)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:239)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:547)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @b9afc07
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:335)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:278)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:196)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:190)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.findMethod(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:51)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.findMethod(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:58)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.findAddURLMethod(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:42)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.<clinit>(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:36)
... 14 more
```

Could anyone please tell where I am making a mistake.
Thank you

*****************************UPDATE************************************

I tried to install in a new way.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

And when I try to launch it I get the following error in a dialog box

```
An error has occurred. See the log file
/home/shiv/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1488271982409.log.
```

Below are the details of the Log file

```
!SESSION 2017-02-28 14:16:16.279    -----------------------------------------------

eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=9-ea
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -clean -initialize

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-02-28 14:16:16.693
!MESSAGE error loading hook: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseHookConfigurator
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @402a079c
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:335)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:278)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:196)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:190)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findMethod(BaseStorage.java:174)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findMethod(BaseStorage.java:181)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findAddURLMethod(BaseStorage.java:165)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.<init>(BaseStorage.java:135)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseHookConfigurator.addHooks(BaseHookConfigurator.java:24)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookRegistry.loadConfigurators(HookRegistry.java:178)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookRegistry.initialize(HookRegistry.java:100)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.<init>(BaseAdaptor.java:98)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:473)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.createAdaptor(EclipseStarter.java:737)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:258)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:547)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-02-28 14:16:16.795
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:123)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:192)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:262)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:547)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: Perhaps it should go with `sudo ./eclipse-inst`, and if you prefer the repo version then `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install eclipse`, but note would not be the latest.

Comment: pls add the __14 more lines__

Comment: I get the same error even with sudo ./eclipse-inst

Comment: Do u need the latest version, and pls add those `14` lines absent fro error message

Comment: Well, I am trying to those 14 lines but however I try to arrange the size of terminal I cant see them. COuld you please tell how can I see them

Comment: Hi George, I tried with the method you mentioned but I am still getting an error. Please check the updated version of my question

Comment: Did you try installing via `apt-get`

Comment: yes I have done like that, please check the lines I added in post after UPDATE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54484/discussion-between-shivanand-t-and-george).

Answer (score 3):

Are you installing the Eclipse from Ubuntu Repository(which has a very old version) or from Internet?

I can give you a better tip to install Eclipse easily on any Ubuntu higher than 14.04.

First you launch java from [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/install-oracle-java-9-in-ubuntu-linux.html) PPA(it will put the java jdk very easy on Linux).

After that, you can download Eclipse from it's [website](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/neon/R2a/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz) and launch from its GUI application.(Don't need to install it from terminal, I never install Eclipse from Terminal.)

Comment: yes I did it this way, it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a temporary solution. 
If I change my Java to version 8 everything works fine. Earlier I tried with version 9 and found those errors

Comment: Eclipse 3.8, which is very old, does not support Java 9. Full support will be in Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) later this year. The current Eclipse Neon (4.6.2) should run on Java 9.

Comment: My current version is Eclipse Neon 4.6.2 but it did not work on Java 9

Comment: OK, so they still haven't fixed all the problems. In which case only Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) will run on Java 9. There are Milestone releases of this but it won't be fully released until June 2017.